# creating a folder on sd with subfolders

Tags: android, eclipse

I got a problem with the following code:

```
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myapp/folderone/foldertwo");
    boolean success = false;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdir();
    }
    if (!success) {
    } else {
    }
```

but its simply not working I also added the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Hope someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to use `mkdirs()` instead of `mkdir()` only, this worked for me.

Example:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myapp/folderone/foldertwo");
    boolean success = false;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdirs();
    }
    if (!success) {
    } else {
    }
```

Comment: oh man how could i be that blind searching for a solution since hours

Comment: that's the everyday life of a developer ^^... Upvotes and Accepts are appreciated ;)

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried calling `mkdirs()` instead of `mkdir()`?

mkdir will only create the single folder specified. In your case "foldertwo".

mkdirs will create the folder specified (foldertwo) along with all other required folders in the path (myapp & folderone)